# How to best approach moving files between projects in TFS 2010 while maintaining changes to original files?

Tags: version-control, tfs

How to best approach moving files between projects in TFS 2010 while maintaining changes to original files?

I have a situation where I have an asp.net mvc 4 project that uses views and controllers located in two separate projects respectfully; I want these files moved to the web project, then, I want to remove the existing view and controller projects from the solution.

Two issues.

1. There will be changes being made to the existing view/controller
   code while all this is taking place, and I want to maintain those
   changes.  What is the best way to do this using TFS 2010?
2. Would be nice if there
   were a TFS 2010 "Share Folder as Link" because there are over 600 views
   alone; is there a way to not spend a month sharing each file as a
   link if it comes down to that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think creating a private NuGet repository and creating a package might be a solution.

Comment: @discens sompin tells me that this can be performed pretty easy using TFS, but alas, I'm not an expert...yet :S